# How to change the color of non-selected item in QComboBox using stylesheets?

Tags: qt, stylesheet, qcombobox

I would like to change the style of the QComboBox. I would like exactly to put the text of the non-selected item's text (FR, ES, IT, ..) in white because they are in black.

[image]

This is the used style sheet :

```css
QComboBox
{
    background-color:black;
    border-color:white;
    color:red;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: solid;
    padding: 1px 0px 1px 3px;
    selection-color:white;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To change the style of the items of a combobox, you can style the inner QAbstractItemView

Example:

```css
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    background-color: rgb(41,41,41);
    color: white;
 
    selection-background-color: rgb(88, 88, 88);
    selection-color: rgb(200, 200, 200);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

While [dydil's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347732/17726418) will work just fine, if you want further control via selectors and pseudo-states over the `QComboBox`, you will need to use `QComboBox::setView()`.

An example using pseudo states:

```css
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item{color: blue;}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:hover{color: red;}
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:selected{background-color: green;}
```

Then add the view with:

```cpp
myComboBox->setView(new QListView);
```