# How to change QComboBox's first item style when there is no selection

Tags: qt, qtstylesheets, qcombobox

I have a QComboBox with no preselected item. When I first open it, the first item has a light blue color. After I move the cursor on the dropdown list, the hovered item gets dark blue, and there is no more light blue colored entry.

Why is the first item light blue, and how can I change its color using QSS?

[image] [image]

```cpp
ui->cb1->addItems({"1111", "2222"});
ui->cb1->setEditable(true);
ui->cb1->lineEdit()->setPlaceholderText(tr("Please select"));
ui->cb1->setCurrentIndex(-1);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The partially highlighted item you see is the *current index* of the popup (a QListView).

Qt item views have two similar but independent states: *current* items and *selected* items (see the table from the [Model/View programming](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/model-view-programming.html#current-item-and-selected-items) documentation).

The current item (or index) is primarily related to focus and editing, there can only be *one* current index for a view.

The selected index indicates a selection that could correspond to one, more, or no indexes.

Those two aspects are often commonly related: the current index is normally the selected index, or is part of a selection. In reality, the current index can also be *outside* the selection: this is similar to what happens when you deselect an icon from a group selection.

When an item view receives focus, and no current index has been explicitly set, it automatically tries to find the first available/selectable index in its model (using [`moveCursor()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qabstractitemview.html#moveCursor)), and sets it as its *current index*, but without selecting it.

This is exactly what happens in a combo box when the popup is shown: if a valid index is set in the combo, the view will automatically make it the current *and* selected index, but if the combo index is `-1` there is no valid index set, so it sets the first item as its *current*, without selecting it.

The color you're seeing is caused by your current style ("fusion"), which chooses to use a semi transparent color for the "focus frame" based on the palette `Highlight` role. Other styles may not draw anything at all.

If you want to change that color, you can use style sheets with the `item:focus:!selected` selector:

```css
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:focus:!selected {
    background-color: orange;
}
```

Alternatively, if you want to completely avoid that behavior, just explicitly set the current index to the view to an invalid index right after setting the -1 index:

```cpp
ui->cb1->setCurrentIndex(-1);
ui->cb1->view()->setCurrentIndex(QModelIndex());
```

Answer (score 2):

Depending on what you want, different solutions can be used. Based on the appearance of your screenshots, you seem to be using the Fusion style.
Therefore, I have tested the below solutions in that same style.

#### Option 1: Remove this light-blue highlight completely.

The CSS you can apply to your `QComboBox` is set the `outline` property to `none`.
With that said, the `outline` property does not work perfectly in Qt, so a bit of styling is required to adjust the items from the drop-down:

```css
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    outline:none;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item {
    border: none;
    color:black;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:hover {
    color:white;
    background-color:darkgray;
}
```

#### Option 2: Change the selection background color and have a focus highlight that is in a matching light color

You can simply use `selection-background-color`/`selection-color` as was pointed out in the accepted answer linked in the comments ([there](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43347732/20143744)):

```css
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    selection-background-color: darkgray;
    selection-color: white;
}
```

This option works, I think, only in style Fusion. To get the same result in a different style such as Windows, do it manually using option 3 below.

#### Option 3: Independently set a color for the focused item

For that, you can apply the style sheet below. Note that I made it red, but you can of course pick the same color or a manually-picked lighter color as when items are hovered.

```css
QComboBox QAbstractItemView {
    outline:none;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item:focus {
    background-color:red;
}

QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item::hover,
QComboBox QAbstractItemView::item::selected {
    color:white;
    background-color:darkgray;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

<sup>This answer is only complementary to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77802796/17726418), and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77800878/17726418). It only explains the source of that partially-transparent highlight color, which is what appears as light blue.</sup>

---

What appears to be light blue is actually a QLinearGradient, and is specific to Fusion Style. It's used to fill the [`PE_FrameFocusRect`](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qstyle.h.html#106), which is a generic focus indicator.

[image: Show focus rect by changing focus through widgets using tab]

From the source code of QFusionStyle, specifically in [`QFusionStyle::drawPrimitive`](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qfusionstyle.cpp.html#_ZNK12QFusionStyle13drawPrimitiveEN6QStyle16PrimitiveElementEPK12QStyleOptionP8QPainterPK7QWidget), we can see how [`case PE_FrameFocusRect`](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qfusionstyle.cpp.html#827) is handled:

```cpp
case PE_FrameFocusRect:
    if (const QStyleOptionFocusRect *fropt = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionFocusRect *>(option)) {
        //### check for d->alt_down
        if (!(fropt->state & State_KeyboardFocusChange))
            return;
        QRect rect = option->rect;
        painter->save();
        painter->setRenderHint(QPainter::Antialiasing, 
                               true);
        painter->translate(0.5, 
                           0.5);
        QColor fillcolor = highlightedOutline;
        fillcolor.setAlpha(80);
        painter->setPen(fillcolor.darker(
            120));
        fillcolor.setAlpha(30);
        QLinearGradient gradient(rect.topLeft(), rect.bottomLeft());
        gradient.setColorAt(0, fillcolor.lighter(
                                   160));
        gradient.setColorAt(1, 
                            fillcolor);
        painter->setBrush(gradient);
        painter->drawRoundedRect(option->rect.adjusted(0, 0, -1, -1), 1, 
                                 1);
        painter->restore();
    }
    break;
```

`painter` uses `gradient` as a brush, `gradient` uses `fillcolor` as its stops' color, and `fillcolor` is just `highlightedOutline` made partially transparent, which in turn, is just the highlight role color, and is obtained through [`QColor QFusionStylePrivate::highlightedOutline`](https://codebrowser.dev/qt6/qtbase/src/widgets/styles/qfusionstyle_p_p.h.html#_ZNK19QFusionStylePrivate18highlightedOutlineERK8QPalette):

```cpp
QColor highlightedOutline(const QPalette &pal) const {
    QColor highlightedOutline = highlight(pal).darker(125);
    if (highlightedOutline.value() > 160)
        highlightedOutline.setHsl(highlightedOutline.hue(), highlightedOutline.saturation(), 160);
    return highlightedOutline;
}
```

---

For comparison, Windows Style depends on the current background color, specifically the QStyleOptionFocusRect's, and if invalid, the painter's:

```cpp
case PE_FrameFocusRect:
    if (const QStyleOptionFocusRect *fropt = qstyleoption_cast<const QStyleOptionFocusRect *>(opt)) {
        //### check for d->alt_down
        if (!(fropt->state & State_KeyboardFocusChange) && !proxy()->styleHint(SH_UnderlineShortcut, opt))
            return;
        QRect r = opt->rect;
        p->save();
        p->setBackgroundMode(Qt::TransparentMode);
        QColor bg_col = fropt->backgroundColor;
        if (!bg_col.isValid())
            bg_col = p->background().color();
        // Create an "XOR" color.
        QColor patternCol((bg_col.red() ^ 0xff) & 0xff,
                          (bg_col.green() ^ 0xff) & 0xff,
                          (bg_col.blue() ^ 0xff) & 0xff);
        p->setBrush(QBrush(patternCol, Qt::Dense4Pattern));
        p->setBrushOrigin(r.topLeft());
        p->setPen(Qt::NoPen);
        p->drawRect(r.left(), r.top(), r.width(), 1);    // Top
        p->drawRect(r.left(), r.bottom(), r.width(), 1); // Bottom
        p->drawRect(r.left(), r.top(), 1, r.height());   // Left
        p->drawRect(r.right(), r.top(), 1, r.height());  // Right
        p->restore();
    }
    break;
```